http request in get with flutter works with jsonplaceholder but not with my website
I am trying to do an HTTP request with flutter, with the konamicash.com/connexion_bdd_flutter, I have no answer even no error, but with the same code with the URL of
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1
echo json_encode(\["message"=\>"requete ok"\]);


    fetchData() async { 
         var url = Uri.parse('https://konamicash.com/connexion_bdd_flutter'); 
         var response = await http.get(url);
           }
         if (response.statusCode == 200) {
         print('sa fonctionne: ${response.body}');
         } else {
             print('error');
         }
     }


Import http package as
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Try below code with try/catch block for errors and data response.
Future<void> fetchData() async {
  try {
    var url = Uri.parse('https://konamicash.com/connexion_bdd_flutter');
    var response = await http.get(url);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('sa fonctionne: ${response.body}');
    } else {
      print('Error: ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('An error occurred: $e');
  }
}


thank you very much , your code works , i have an error now , it says: An error occurred: ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error., uri=https://konamicash.com/connexion_bdd_flutter

Did you find a solution or are you still getting the error?

Hi i hope you are doing well and sorry for replying so late, well it works well now i found a solution and thank you again... but i have another issue i can't pass variables form a page to another with simple code and i don't know where i am wrong? can you check it please, it is going to be veeeeeery helpful, thank you

@DeenanDjigbenou, you still getting error for last comment?
And if you found a solution from posted answer, accept that answer so that others can easily find a solution to the same problem.

I've tested your function, and it's working properly. However, in your function, there were syntax mistakes, and the condition was placed outside the function.
 fetchData() async {
    var url = Uri.parse('https://konamicash.com/connexion_bdd_flutter');
    var response = await http.get(url);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print('sa fonctionne: ${response.body}');
      } else {
        print('error');
      }
  }

I’ve made some corrections to your code and added certain changes. However, I recommend following proper syntax when working with Future. Below, I’ve redefined your function correctly.
I've defined the return type of the function and added a try-catch block for error handling.
Please run below code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
   Future<void> fetchData() async {
    var url = Uri.parse('https://konamicash.com/connexion_bdd_flutter');
    var response = await http.get(url);

    try {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print('sa fonctionne: ${response.body}');
      } else {
        print('error');
      }
    } catch (e, s) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          const Text('Hi, I am testing this nee app'),
          ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: const Text('Make API call')),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}



i have copied and paste your code and it doesn't work for the moment, i don't have error message too... but when i try the code of droidflutter, it tells me that an errror occured and ClientException: XMLHttpRequest error., uri=konamicash.com/connexion_bdd_flutter

@DeenanDjigbenou can you please share the minimal code where I can re-produce your issue?

yes i will send you my code:

https://pastebin.com/kTSPZBHg, you can see my code right here and thank you for your help

"requete ok"]);

?>  here is the simple php code of the page i want to get the info from
@DeenanDjigbenou can you call fetchDate() method in initState() is it proper working. Also, check whether you are sending acceptable headers in your API?

just bellow the override of my statefulwidget i put,fetchDate() like this: class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
const MyApp({super.key});
@override
initState(
fetchDate()
)
State createState() => _MyAppState();
}, i have an error A function body must be provided.
Try adding a function body.dart(missing_function_body)

And please what do you mean by acceptable headers in my api? maybe i am wrong but i think the issue comes from the php page since when i change the url for jsonplaceholder.typicode.com it works properly

I edited my answer please check it and run the code in your editor. Also, one more thing please remove headers and call your function on any button onPressed. Because in Postman it's working fine

thank you very much for you help,well it works when i use a phone  emulator ,and my app is paused by an exception thrown, i am obliged to click on play to resume the app and then i have the response from my website, so how can i run the app without always click on play???

can you please tell me which exception you are getting? Attach the SS of the play and resume button.

excuse me if i reply late, i am very new at coding, so excuse me for the question but what is SS of the play and resume button??

can you share the screenshot of the terminal where you need to press the resume button so, I can guide you on how can you do it without pressing the button all the time

Hi i hope you are doing well and sorry for replying so late, well it works well now i found a solution and thank you again... but i have another issue i can't pass variables form a page to another with simple code and i don't know where i am wrong? can you check it please, it is going to be veeeeeery helpful, thank you

@DeenanDjigbenou can you please share the re-producible code so I can check and help to resolve your issue?

Ok i Will send you in a couple of hours...thank you again

ok you can find my reproducible code just right here, https://pastebin.com/ztQc1q1P, i have a problem with posting question on stackoverflow... thank you for your time and help

You are passing TextEditingController new object every time if you want the same value on a new page then pass controllermail.value or controllermail.text the same for the password as well. Also, please do not pass the key to the next screen. There is no need to pass the key. Just check it and let me know
